# Sorting Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-analysis

I have a multi-index pandas groupby dataframe I am having problem with sorting the sum and the average values.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se8WK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort_values()

```
cost_per_brand = dataset[['BRAND','RATE']]
cost_per_brand.groupby('BRAND').agg(['sum','mean']).round(1).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Comment: sort_values with multiple arguments returns an error.

Comment: You can try this `cost_per_brand = dataset[['BRAND','RATE']]
cost_per_brand.groupby('BRAND').agg(['sum','mean']).round(1).sort_values(by=[ 'BRAND'], inplace=True, key=lambda x: x.str.lower())`

Comment: Also you can provide sample dataset

Comment: Thanks @Gaston Alex. I was able to sort it by first making it a data frame object and sort afterwards.